# Can a List Dialog be populated from the database?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, onclicklistener, android-dialog

I have a ListView that holds a certain number of Names, when I clicked an item from the ListView I want a ListDialog pop up displaying a certain data from the database. Is that possible?

If YES(if it is possible) after I click an item from the List Dialog it is also possible that another List Dialog will come out from it? Like List Dialog nested?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just get a new DialogFragment calling some newInstance() with some args to specify what you want.

In your list activity:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor c = (Cursor) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    int index = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME));
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(index);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

In your DialogFragment class:

```
static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int index) {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int index = getArguments().getInt("index");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    Dialog dialog;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final Cursor c = someDatabaseHelper.getData(index);
    builder.setCursor(c, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            c.moveToPosition(which);
            int idWeWant = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(STRING_ID_WE_WANT));
            //you can make another dialog here using the same method
        }
    });
    dialog = builder.create();
    return builder.create();
}
```